# Need info on handling system notification on iPhone in automation

Tags: ios, iphone, automation

We initiate pairing with iPhone,
On iPhone a notification “Do you want to pair with this device” with 2 buttons “Pair” and “cancel” is displayed.
I need to click on this “Pair” button.

I notice that this notification displayed is not part of the any mobile (iPhone) application instead its system notification.

With the current tool, I am unable to click on this “Pair” button, hence can you please suggest an automation tool for iPhone which can perform click on this “Pair” button displayed as part of system notification?

Answer (score 0):

its true you can not click buttons on alert and notification with inbuild automation. automation have inbuild functionality which cancel notification and alert by click on cancel

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Instrument tool provided by apple then also it is possible to tap on "Pair". Only thing you need to do is register a callback for alert before your alert come. So limitation with this is if your alert come at starting point only then it is not possible with this tool but if this alert comes in between then definitely you can tap on "Pair".

You can see in UIAutomation doc hon how to register a callback for alert.

If not able to then I can help you more.